# Usb webcamera not detected in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have build a web application(using reactjs) that detects USB cameras and loads the preview on the website.
I have built it using react-webcam package.
I get the devices connected using

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```

The application works perfectly fine in multiple browsers(chrome, firefox, edge) in desktop. but does not work in mobile browsers(chrome, firefox, edge).

if I try to connect the USB camera using the mobile application to detect the camera, it works but not the website that I have built.
and I am sure I have given the browser(website) camera permissions.
I have two, three USB cameras for which the mobile and web applications are built, but none of them are getting detected by the website in mobile browsers. (but is getting detected in desktop browsers).

I tried to detect my USB cameras through https://webcamtests.com/ and the webcam test website detects the cameras through my desktop browser but not browsers in mobile. (my external USB cameras)

I can't understand what could be wrong, that it is not getting detected in only mobile browsers. I have made sure the device is properly connected using my android mobile application and it does get detected in my mobile application on the phone but not on my website.

componentdidmount function

```
componentDidMount=()=>{


    let self = this
    // code to get access to the camera
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {
      width: { min: 1920, ideal: 1920 },
      height: { min: 1920, ideal: 1080 },
    }})


  navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
.then(devices => {
  devices.forEach(function(device) {

    if (device.label.startsWith("Doccamera") || device.label=="LiteArray USB2.0") {  
self.setState({did:device.deviceId})
    }

  });

  this.setState({initialRender: true})
}).catch(err => console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message))
}
```

Render function

```
render(){
  const videoConstraints = {

    width: { min: 1920 },
    height: { min: 1920  },

    aspectRatio: 1.777777778,
      facingMode: "user",
      deviceId : { exact: this.state.did } 
    }
return(
      <Webcam
                  className="mt-2"
                  width="53%"
                  height="53%"
          audio={false}
          ref={this.setRef}
          screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
          onUserMedia={this.previewLoadComplete}

          onUserMediaError={previewLoadError}
          screenshotQuality={1}
          minScreenshotWidth={1280}
          minScreenshotHeight={960}
          videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
          id="webcamscreen" href="#"
        data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"/>
)
}
```

Expected Result: camera preview is displayed on the screen when I plug in my USB camera to my mobile phone and open my website with permissions in chrome browser(mobile browser)

Actual Result: camera preview is not displayed on the screen when I plug in my USB camera to my mobile phone and open my website with permissions in chrome browser(mobile browser)

Thank you for your time

Comment: for sake of curiosity: you are trying to connect a webcam via USB to a mobile phone? How? The phones are full of internal webcams (front and rear cameras) so why you should plug in a new camera?

Comment: I am trying to create a web application that takes preview from only usb cameras that are plugged in. just a personal project for developing my skills. I am connecting the webcameras using otg cable from USB. Thank you for your time

Comment: the OTG protocol supports only driver-free devices. A webcam is not driver-free at all. You can use keyboard, hdd, mouse but a webcam is definitively not compatible

Comment: but then when I connect the USB camera through OTG for my android application, the Android application detected my USB camera in mobile. any idea why it is working via mobile application but not for my website? how come the OTG protocol allows for android application ?

Comment: also can you please explain what you mean by driver free devices? Thank you

Comment: driver-free devices are those that doesn't require a driver to be set up in order to work. A printer, a webcam and some other more complex devices require a driver installed to handle. A mouse, a keyboard, an hard drive usually are operative as soon as you plug them without installing any driver

Comment: Thank you very much for that info, do you have any idea why the web camera would work as soon as I plug it in through otg for my android mobile application? whereas for web application it is not achievable in my android phone?